# Firebase Rule for Data Validation

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Assuming a data structure like below, I want a rule that disallows adding new car makes, for example users cannot add "toyota".  So, I need to .validate such that the .update must match an existing make.

I have tried using $cars with ".validate": "newData.val().contains($cars)" and all kind of other ways with no luck.  Any help is appreciated.

My code is:

```
function setModel(model,make,key){
    if (model && make && key){
        var carsRef = ref.child('cars');
        var makeRef = carsRef.child(make);
        var modelRef = makeRef.child(model);
        var obj = {};
        obj[key] = true;           
        modelRef.update(obj, onComplete);
    }
}
```

The firebase looks like:

```
{
"cars" : {
   "chevrolet" : {
      "silverado" : {
         "id192874623" : true,
         "id786766663" : true
      }
   },
   "ford" : {
      "taurus" : {
         "id736273627" : true
      }
   },
   "honda" : {
      "accord" : {
         "id635263535" : true
      }
   }
}}
```

Comment: If you have tried to write the security rules already, add them to your question. It allows us to see what you may be doing wrong, instead of having to start from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disallow adding new car brands:

```
"cars": {
  "$brand": {
    ".validate": "data.exists()"
  }
}
```

This is covered in the section on [existing data vs new data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-data-variables) of the documentation.